# How can I add background color inside html code using beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

With beautifulsoup I get the html code of a site, let say it's this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>My First Heading</h1>
<p>My first paragraph.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

How I can add this line `body {background-color:#b0c4de;}` inside the **head** tag using beautifulsoup?

Lets say python code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cgi, cgitb, urllib2, sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site = "www.example.com"
page = urllib2.urlopen(site)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
```

Comment: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#modifying-the-tree

Comment: Tichodroma thank you... you could write it as answer so I could give you best answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
soup.head.append('body {background-color:#b0c4de;}')
```

But you should [create a `<style>` tag](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#beautifulsoup-new-string-and-new-tag) before.

For instance:

```
head = soup.head
head.append(soup.new_tag('style', type='text/css'))
head.style.append('body {background-color:#b0c4de;}')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'